# How to remove the last decimal place of 0 from the y axis?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm creating a line chart with ggplot2, and I want to remove the last decimal place of 0 from the y axis. Executing the following code, you will see that the y axis has the ticks of 0.050, 0.010, 0.005, and 0.001. However, I want the ticks of 0.05, 0.01, 0.005, and 0.001, removing the final 0. How can I achieve this?

```r
tibble(
  timepoints = 1:100,
  alpha      = 1 - exp(log(0.95)/(1:100))
) %>% 
  ggplot(
    .,
    aes(
      x = timepoints,
      y = alpha
    )
  ) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line() +
  scale_x_continuous(
    n.breaks = 6
  ) +
  scale_y_continuous(
    breaks = c(
      0.05,
      0.01,
      0.005,
      0.001
      )
  ) +
  theme(
    text = element_text(size=30)
  )
```

Comment: Use the `labels` argument to your call to `scale_y_continuous`.

Comment: @Limey Got it and I got what I wanted! You can post the comment with the complete code as an answer. I will definitely upvote if you do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comments by @Limey, you can use the `labels` argument to set the desired text. I would use a function to strip the tailing zeros from the decimals. This way, if you change your breaks in the future, the labels will still have you desired effect.

```r
tibble(
 timepoints = 1:100,
 alpha      = 1 - exp(log(0.95)/(1:100))
) %>% 
 ggplot(aes(x = timepoints,y = alpha )) +
 geom_point() +
 geom_line() +
 scale_x_continuous( n.breaks = 6) +
 scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(0.05,0.01,0.005,0.001),
                    labels = function(x) sub("0+$", "", x)) +
 theme(text = element_text(size=30))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer and it's great to know how to get the effect without depending on the breaks, too!